# How to spit string to get each text with special signal?

Tags: javascript

I have string like that : `Stackoverflow is a useful Forum for [all][people][over the world] and I like this rum`

I want get text from string above to have result :

```
text1 = "all";

text2 = "people";

text3 = "over the world";
```

Comment: Does your string actually contain brackets?

Comment: @isherwood : Yes. It's signal to spit.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493027/javascript-return-string-between-square-brackets

Comment: @isherwood : but with more than 1 brackets? How to get each of them as my example.

Comment: Are you sure that you mean [spitting](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/spit)?

Comment: Please answer below my post. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
var str = 'Stackoverflow is a useful Forum for [all][people][over the world] and I like this rum';
var matches = str.match(/\[.*?]/g);
console.log(String(matches[0]).replace( /(^.*\[|\].*$)/g, '' ));
console.log(String(matches[1]).replace( /(^.*\[|\].*$)/g, '' ));
console.log(String(matches[2]).replace( /(^.*\[|\].*$)/g, '' ));
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/h8PTu/)