# how to extract an array from a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have a string which contains array in it and bracket , i want to extract data from it .

```
    let vr = "- [Next.js Documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs) - learn about Next.js features and API."
```

how can i dynamically identify if an array is present in this string , like take `[Next.js Documentation]` since it is an array. Please help me on this issue

Comment: That's not an array. [That's markdown notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) (which, coincidentally, I just used to create that link). The square brackets contain the text, and the parentheses contain the link.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493027/javascript-return-string-between-square-brackets

Comment: @DnoTech I added an answer. Did you get a chance to look into that. Hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observation, `[Next.js Documentation]` is a string not an array. Element in this array should be a `string` type.

If you just want to access a string, You can check this demo **:**

```js
let vr = "- [Next.js Documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs) - learn about Next.js features and API.";

const newSubStr = vr.substring(vr.indexOf('['), vr.indexOf(']') + 1);

console.log(newSubStr); // [Next.js Documentation]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex with javascript's [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

The regex pattern to match anything enclosed by brackets is `/\[(.*?)\]/gm`. You can check [here](https://regex101.com/).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```js
let vr = "- [Next.js Documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs) - learn about Next.js features and API."
const regex = /\[([^\]]+)\]\(([^)]+)\)/g;
let match;
let result = [];
while ((match = regex.exec(vr)) !== null) {
  result.push(match[1]);
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let vr = "- [Next.js Documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs) - learn about Next.js features and API."

const re = /\[([^]*?)]/g;
let match = re.exec(vr);
if (match !== null) {
    console.log(match[1]);
} else {
    // not matched
}
```